# Gitlab CI - create cluster, run pods, run app in pod, run tests, and then delete cluster

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a small question.
Is it possible to create by gitlab CI ( gitlab-ci.yml), kubernetes cluster with pods to integration tests?
I need to run ~10 pods with databases etc and after that run my app’s test.
After tests i need to remove all created before pods and send feedback about to gitlab ci.

Is this flow possible?
Best! :slight_smile:

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GKE [it seems](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/quick_start_guide.html) gitlab-ci has a nice integration with it.

In my case as a AWS user I found [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) facilitates a lot the setup of a cluster. I found [a script](https://gist.github.com/chapati23/7f5400413b2a01fa2c53bb196b660237) that automates everything you need in AWS. There is also a good tutorial [here](https://medium.com/containermind/how-to-create-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-aws-in-few-minutes-89dda10354f4). Tools like [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) may be also useful.
Besides all that, because your cluster is temporary it might be a good idea to just use **minikube** if your requirements don't include multiple nodes and automated load testing.

Comment: No, we have our own cloud. Some solution is creating docker in docker structure. Gitlab have workers, and problem is in one worker = one pod. When project has 12 integrations we need to wait long time to docker-compose turn on all containers. It would be the best, if from the level of gitlab-ci file i could define other pods and after build kill them all.